# Geonodes - How to use Material Index?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a node setup that has multiple geometries combined with a Join Geometry node.  I want to give each geometry a unique material, but I want to automate it so that for every object, the next material in an index is automatically assigned.

In other words, if there are multiple objects then object 1 is assigned MATERIAL 1, the second is assigned MATERIAL 2, and the third gets MATERIAL 3, and so on.

Is there a way to do this with nodes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The node `Set Material` assigns a material to a geometry. However, exactly one material.

Therefore the node `Set Material Index` can only be applied to a geometry which has been assigned several materials before.

This can be either the geometry containing the *Geometry Nodes* modifier, but also geometry created in *Geometry Nodes*.

If you create geometry in *Geometry Nodes*, you have to assign several materials to it, which is possible by lining up several `Set Material` nodes and then selecting the respective slot with `Set Material Index`.

But this is not very flexible, because you would have to use many nodes in a row manually.

But there is a little trick:

[image]

Here you use the original geometry, to which several materials were assigned in the *Material Properties* before, as a base.

The trick is: By adding more objects afterwards with `Join Geometry`, or as in this example with `Geometry to Instances`, these inherit the materials of the base object.

In addition, these get their own index, which can be used here as *Material Index* at the same time.

The original geometry should not be used here in the end, so I mark it with the node `Capture Attribute` and remove it afterwards. The captured materials as well as their material index are kept in the rest of the geometry.

In this way I can assign each object its own material index, and the materials defined by you are taken from the *Material Properties*.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.3+)*</sub>

Comment: This isn't as simple as I'd hoped but definitely workable, and I learned a thing, so thank you!!