# How to select points based on whether they changed their position?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'd like to mark points, that have changed their position for a geometry node simulation:
[image]

My idea to solve this, is to compare the position of the points before moving to their position afterwards. If the position changed, they get a new material to indicate just that.

This doesn't work and I can't make out why

Here is a .blend file with the attempts (and some other stuff): [image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `Set Material` node works with the *Face* domain. Since you have instances, not a mesh, there are no faces to evaluate the comparison on. You can test this by using an *Index* selection like below. Even though they are all instances, `Set Material` thinks of the the given indices as face indices:

[image]

You can `Realize Instances` before `Set Material` to make the setup work, but obviously that might not be desirable. In that case, you might wanna work around the problem by employing a node that can filter instances using your comparison setup; `Separate Geometry`, for instance:

[image]<sub>*I'm also using an Index > Modulo 2 for Set Position's Selection, to move only every other cube to better showcase the fitering*</sub>

Here's an earlier question dealing with an adjacent issue: [*How to use Geometry Nodes Material Index with Instances?*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/280233/how-to-use-geometry-nodes-material-index-with-instances)